# Wordpress changes && into &#038;&#038; in script integrated inside html

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I creating a plugin base on some theme module.
I created a local xampp server and added a fresh Wordpress, without any extension and started creating my plugin.
But on some page I have javascript errors in the javascript code integrated to the html, it seems to change `&&` into `&#038;&#038;`.

I was able to correct the issue with my scripts but it seems that some wordpress things are involved for example in that portion of code:

```
!function(e,a,t){var n,r,o,i=a.createElement("canvas"),p=i.getContext&&i.getContext("2d");function s(e,t){p.clearRect(0,0,i.width,i.height),p.fillText(e,0,0);e=i.toDataURL();return p.clearRect(0,0,i.width,i.height),p.fillText(t,0,0),e===i.toDataURL()}function c(e){var t=a.createElement("script");t.src=e,t.defer=t.type="text/javascript",a.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(t)}for(o=Array("flag","emoji"),t.supports={everything:!0,everythingExceptFlag:!0},r=0;r<o.length;r++)t.supports[o[r]]=function(e){if(p&#038;&#038;p.fillText)switch(p.textBaseline="top",p.font="600 32px Arial",e){case"flag":return s("\ud83c\udff3\ufe0f\u200d\u26a7\ufe0f","\ud83c\udff3\ufe0f\u200b\u26a7\ufe0f")?!1:!s("\ud83c\uddfa\ud83c\uddf3","\ud83c\uddfa\u200b\ud83c\uddf3")&#038;&#038;!s("\ud83c\udff4\udb40\udc67\udb40\udc62\udb40\udc65\udb40\udc6e\udb40\udc67\udb40\udc7f","\ud83c\udff4\u200b\udb40\udc67\u200b\udb40\udc62\u200b\udb40\udc65\u200b\udb40\udc6e\u200b\udb40\udc67\u200b\udb40\udc7f");case"emoji":return!s("\ud83e\udef1\ud83c\udffb\u200d\ud83e\udef2\ud83c\udfff","\ud83e\udef1\ud83c\udffb\u200b\ud83e\udef2\ud83c\udfff")}return!1}(o[r]),t.supports.everything=t.supports.everything&#038;&#038;t.supports[o[r]],"flag"!==o[r]&#038;&#038;(t.supports.everythingExceptFlag=t.supports.everythingExceptFlag&#038;&#038;t.supports[o[r]]);t.supports.everythingExceptFlag=t.supports.everythingExceptFlag&#038;&#038;!t.supports.flag,t.DOMReady=!1,t.readyCallback=function(){t.DOMReady=!0},t.supports.everything||(n=function(){t.readyCallback()},a.addEventListener?(a.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",n,!1),e.addEventListener("load",n,!1)):(e.attachEvent("onload",n),a.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",function(){"complete"===a.readyState&#038;&#038;t.readyCallback()})),(e=t.source||{}).concatemoji?c(e.concatemoji):e.wpemoji&#038;&#038;e.twemoji&#038;&#038;(c(e.twemoji),c(e.wpemoji)))}(window,document,window._wpemojiSettings);
```

I don't know where it is but that's not mine, how can I correct the problem ?

EDIT: it seems to be in a wp-includes/js/wp-emoji...